# Error when performing expand.grid() on dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I was preforming `expand.grid()` on `subdb`, how to tackle this?

```
full <- with(subdb, expand.grid(sort(unique(UserId), sort(unique(ProductId))))
```

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
>     invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'

Why I am getting this error?

`subdb` is a data frame holding 'UserId', 'ProductId', and 'Score'.

Comment: subdb is a data frame holding UserId,ProductId,and Score.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a parenthesis in the first call to `sort()`, namely it should be `sort(unique(UserId))` not `sort(unique(UserId)`.

For example, the following works for me:

```
subdb <- data.frame("UserId" = sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE),
                    "ProductId" = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 200, replace = TRUE))

full <- with(subdb, expand.grid(sort(unique(UserId)), 
                                sort(unique(ProductId))))

full
```